# Spring boot Validation

Tags: validation, design-patterns, spring-boot

I'm working on spring boot validation and got problem when validating the id variable,

```
@NotNull @Pattern(regexp="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
private Object id;
```

Error is

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Object.
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation‌​.ConstraintValidator‌​Manager.verifyResolv‌​eWasUnique(Constrain‌​tValidatorManager.ja‌​va:218)
```

Help.

Thanks.

Comment: javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Object.
 at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.verifyResolveWasUnique(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:218)

Comment: [`@Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) only works on `String` typed fields.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be a `String`, not `Object`.

```
@NotNull @Pattern(regexp="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
private String id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime for this

```
@NotNull 
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
private DateTime id;
```